# Buildfarm Jenkins devel job unstable

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, devel, jenkins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to fix Jenkins devel job of the package [z_laser_projector](http://wiki.ros.org/z_laser_projector)

I'm having some import errors when running tests ("1.3. run tests" [Console Section](http://build.ros.org/view/Mdev/job/Mdev__z_laser_projector__ubuntu_bionic_amd64/9/console#console-section-3))

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rospkg'

The whole package is developed for python3 in ROS melodic but Jenkins is using python2. I would like to ask if there is any way to force Jenkins configuration in order to run catkin with python3, for example forcing env vars as ROS_PYTHON_VERSION. Or  am I missing something on package.xml?

Check that the build succeeds by running tests on [TravisCI](https://travis-ci.com/github/fada-catec/z_laser_projector/builds/210375194)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368279/buildfarm-jenkins-devel-job-unstable/) by [rluque](https://answers.ros.org/users/55521/rluque/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2020-12-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> The whole package is developed for python3 in ROS melodic [..]

ROS Melodic is Python 2 based. All packages released through the ROS buildfarm will therefore only get to use Python 2.

> but Jenkins is using python2. [..] is there any way to force Jenkins configuration in order to run catkin with python3, for example forcing env vars as ROS_PYTHON_VERSION.

This is not a limitation of the ROS buildfarm, but of ROS Melodic (see also [REP 3: Melodic Morenia](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#melodic-morenia-may-2018-may-2023)).

> Or am I missing something on package.xml?

No. The reason this is not working is because you cannot release a Python 3 package into ROS Melodic.

Or at least, not without some tricks (such as [catkin_virtualenv](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin_virtualenv)).

For native Python 3 support, you'll have to switch to ROS Noetic (and/r ROS 2).

> Check that the build succeeds by running tests on [TravisCI](https://travis-ci.com/github/fada-catec/z_laser_projector/builds/210375194)

Yes, probably because you invoke the build of your workspace like this:

```
catkin_make -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 -DPYTHON_VERSION=3.6 --force-cmake
```

which forces the use of Python 3 in a ROS Melodic workspace (ie: a Python 2-based ROS distro).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rluque](https://answers.ros.org/users/55521/rluque/) on 2021-01-11**:
Thank you very much for your answer, it has been very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Melodic is [configured as](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/index-v4.yaml#L83) a Python 2 distribution.
The default source-build configuration [also uses Python 2](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm_config/blob/production/melodic/source-build.yaml#L5) and changing that for a single package wouldn't work. You would need to add a separate binary distribution of Melodic using Python 3.

---

Originally posted by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) with karma: 906 on 2020-12-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1